# split string to string array without loosing text order

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, .net-2.0

I have a problem that I busted my head for 7 days, so I decide to ask you for help. Here is my problem:

I read data from datagridview (only 2 cell), and fill all given data in stringbuilder, its actually article and price like invoice (bill). Now I add all what I get in stringbuilder in just string with intention to split string line under line, and that part of my code work but not as I wont. Article is one below another but price is one price more left another more right not all in one vertical line, something like this:

```
Bread  10$
Egg    4$
Milk   5$
```

My code:

```
string[] lines;
StringBuilder sbd = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataGridViewRow rowe in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    sbd.Append(rowe.Cells[0].Value).Append(rowe.Cells[10].Value);
    sbd.Append("\n");
}
sbd.Remove(sbd.Length - 1, 1);
string userOutput = sbd.ToString();
lines = userOutput.Split(new string[] { "\r", "\n" },    
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just build `lines[]` directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Trim` method in order to remove existing leading and trailing spaces. With `PadRight` you can automatically add the right number of spaces in order to get a specified total length.

Also use a `List<string>` that grows automatically instead of using an array that you get from splitting what you just put together before:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows) {
    lines.Add( row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim().PadRight(25) +
               row.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Trim());
}
```

But keep in mind that this way of formatting works only if you display the string in a monospaced font (like `Courier New` or `Consolas`). Proportional fonts like `Arial` will yield jagged columns.

Alternatively you can create an array with the right size by reading the number of lines from the `Count` property

```
string[] lines = new string[dataGridView2.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
    lines[i] = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim().PadRight(25) +
               row.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
```

You can also use the `PadLeft` method in order to right align the amounts

```
row.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Trim().PadLeft(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [String Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) ?

```
String myString = "Bread         ;10$;";

String articleName = myString.split(';')[0];
String price = myString.split(';')[1];
```